# An unexpected exception occurred while binding a dynamic operation

Tags: c#, .net

after calling `dynamic service = Activator.CreateInstance()`, I am getting an exception when I call `service.XXX`, even though `service`, contains `XXX` property.

For example:

```
Type importServiceType;
importServiceType = Type.GetType(serviceName, true);
dynamic service = Activator.CreateInstance(importServiceType);
```

when I put a breakpoint and debug, I get:

[image]

This occurs with any of the properties: service.JobId, service.JobDescription etc.

The error:`An unexpected exception occurred while binding a dynamic operation,  Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderInternalCompilerException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was occurring with some code on a couple of lines before.
fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Internally, all type names are fully qualified. This means compiler will reject code if treat two types same. Unless from same assembly, with same namespace and name.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this, and fixed it by applying an alias to the dll i want to force to be used, and specify the dll you want to load.

add an alias to your .csprof file

```
<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json.4.5.3, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b9a188c8922137c6, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\..\Common\Newtonsoft.Json.4.5.3.dll</HintPath>
  <Aliases>Newtonsoft453</Aliases>
</Reference>
```

and then in your .cs file:

```
extern alias Newtonsoft453;
...
using Newtonsoft453::Newtonsoft.Json;
```